# Need to understand how Grails params work

Tags: grails, parameters

I have two questions really.  First, I"m wondering how the  tag interacts with other tags inside of it when you hit the controller.  Specifically, I have a  outside of the  tag, and another inside the  tag.  The textField on the outside of the form tag is in the params once inside the controller, but the textField *inside* the form tag is NOT in the params.  Why is this?

My second question is around working with a  tag.  I am trying to access the values in a  tag in my params once I hit the controller, and they simply aren't there.  I have a  right next to the , and it ends up in the params... but not the .

Here is an example of the .gsp question:

```
<div id="includedNodes">
  <g:textField name="happyTextField" value="I. FEEL. HAPPY!" />
  <g:select name="selectto" id="selectTo" multiple="true"
            size="25" from="${['is', 'this', 'working?']}"/>
</div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
def includedNodes = params.selectTo
def otherIncludedNodes = params.selectto
def textfieldData = params.happyTextField
def hello = "asdf"  // <--- I put a breakpoint here
```

Once the breakpoint is hit, I examine the params, and see that happyTextField is in the params, but selectto is NOT.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think of tags like macros - they simplify the process of outputting HTML but have no direct action on what happens in your controller once the page has made the round trip via a browser. So you need to look at the HTML source in your browser to see what is happening. It makes no difference at this point (to the browser) whether the HTML was hand written, generated by Grails, Java or PHP, its just HTML.

On the controller side, all it is seeing is the standard HTTP request. So you need to look at the request params that the browser is sending.

So for your second question, look at the HTML source in the browser to see why it is not sending the `selectto` param. Maybe you didn't select one/some of the `<option>`s in the form before hitting submit, as only the option values with `selected="selected"` get sent by the browser?

Answer (score 1):

do a view source, or use firefox to see what kind of HTML is actually being created. Make sure you don't have nested  tags or inputs outside of your  tag.  You can also use the addon Httpfox to see precisely what the browser is sending to the server.